# Apache with xDebug loaded but not working?

Tags: apache2, php, xdebug

I've installed the `php5-xdebug` package through `apt-get`, I enabled it with `php5enmod xdebug` and when I run `php -v`, I get this:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Also, `phpinfo()` reports that `xdebug` is enabled.

I'm attempting to integrate this with the PHPStorm IDE (which supports xdebug).

However, I have placed this line: `xdebug_break();` in a file in my web app.

When I do a http request to my app, it seems ot ignore the call to xdebug_break(). It just runs like normal.

*What's going on here?*

Answer (score 1):

Of ocourse, one must remember to pass a HTTP "GET" parameter named 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START` and setting it to the IDE KEY.